# How could you format a full name into just initials? (X.X.X.)

Tags: python, format, names

I'm trying to turn a full name into just the initials from one string. My logic is to capitalize all the names in the string, break the string by the spaces into a list, then select the first character of each index, then join the characters into a single string divided by periods.

I'm having trouble with this and not sure if there's a better way.

Here's my current progress:

```
def main():
    fstn= input("Enter your full name:")

    fstn=fstn.title()
    fstn= fstn.split(" ")
    for i in fstn:
        fstn= i[0]
        print(fstn)


main()
```

This prints out each initial on a different line, how would i finish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi check this example out,

```
def main():
    fstn= input("Enter your full name:")
    fstn=fstn.title()
    fstn= fstn.split(" ")
    out_str = ""
    for i in fstn:
        out_str = out_str + i[0] + "."
    print(out_str)

main()
```

Comment: That works perfectly, the only issue is that I need to separate the initials with a period.                    So if I understand correctly, you initialized the out string, so it was updated every iteration of the loop, correct? Thanks for the help.

Comment: i just added it, check again @MarcusColinHarvison

Comment: Ohh I should've been able  figured that one out by myself. Regardless thanks for your help, this is my first language so it's a challenge to learn how to do these things!

Comment: Will do, in 5 minutes when it allows me. :/

Answer (score 2):

```
def main():
    fstn= input("Enter your full name:")
    print ('.'.join(word[0] for word in fstn.split(" ")).upper()) #for python 3


main()
```